# Find a continuous function having following properties.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

> Which of the following statements is/are true?
>
> 1. There exists a continuous map $f:ℝ\to ℝ$
>      such that $f(ℝ)=\mathbb{Q} $.
> 2. There exists a continuous map $f:ℝ\to ℝ$
>      such that $f(ℝ)=\mathbb{Z} $.
> 3. There exists a continuous map $f:ℝ\to ℝ^2$
>      such that $f(ℝ)=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2: x^2+y^2=1}\}$.
> 4. There exists a continuous map $f:[0,1]\cup[2,3]\to \{0,1\}$

So I try to solve and showed that first option is false, by assuming that there exists a continuous map from $f:ℝ\to ℝ$
such that $f(ℝ)=\mathbb{Q} $.  If there were, then we could find
$a,b ∈ R$ with $f(a) = 1$ and $f(b) = 2$. Either $a < b$ or $b < a$. Let’s suppose $a < b$. Since $f(x)$ is continuous on
$R$ it is also continuous on $[a,b]$. By the intermediate value theorem, and the fact that $1 <
\sqrt{2} < 2$, there exists
a $c ∈ (a,b)$ such that $f(c) =
√ 2$. But $\sqrt{ 2} \not \in Q$, hence $f(R)$, which includes $f(c)$, cannot just be $Q$.

Now my concerns are- 
Can I argue similarly for option 2? My intuition says that option 3 and 4 are correct. But I am unable to find explicit functions so far.

Can anyone help me to clear my doubts? Thanks.

Comment: Did you want $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ in 3. ?

Comment: With 2 there is a short cut you can make use of.  Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ if there existed a contentious map for $\mathbb{Z} $ there would exist a map for $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Long story short, the image of a connected topological space under a continuous map is again connected.

Comment: @uniquesolution yes. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: @QthePlatypus Can you elaborate? Suppose one existed for $\mathbb{Z}$, call it $f$, then we would have $f(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{Z}$. In particular $f(\mathbb{R})\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$. But we also need $f(\mathbb{R})\supseteq\mathbb{Q}$ to obtain equality of sets?

Comment: I missunderstood the question as you have pointed out my reasoning doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $f$ is a continuous function from $X\rightarrow Y$ then $f(X)$ is connected if $X$ is connected . $R$ is connected but $Q$ and $Z$ are not. So the first two are impossible. For third take the map $R\rightarrow R^2$ where $f(t)=(cos (t), sin (t)) $ And for the last define $f(x)=0 $ if $x\in [0,1]$ and $ 1 $ if $ x\in [2,3]$

Comment: Yes but the question requires the image to be entire Z or Q not a mere subset

Comment: I did think about the last function you have mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

Hints for 3: Don't try to find a bijective function; it doesn't exist. What is the name of the set where $x^2+y^2=1$? Have you studied that set before?

Hints for 4: Don't try to find a nice formula, like a polynomial. You can define a function in English if you want. What do you need the function to do?

Comment: As stated 4 doesn't require $f$ to be surjective, so it is possible to satisfy with a formula.

Comment: @stewbasic Ah, good catch. Well, given the context, that might just be an oversight.

Comment: The set is for circles.

Comment: @KushalBhuyan Right, the set is the unit circle, so that's a hint to think about functions that map to the unit circle. The study of the unit circle is trigonometry, which provides the right functions.